# Make Change Format of selected TextField in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, action

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change format of any selected textfield in AS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662374/change-format-of-any-selected-textfield-in-as3)

i create many textfield at click event.now  i want to change textformat at any select textField. But textformat applied latest create textfield.  i tried follwing

```
function _txtbtn(e:*):void
{
    myText = new TextField();
    mc3 = new MovieClip();
    myText.text = "text...";
    myFormat.font = "Arial";
    myFormat.color = txt_color()
    myText.setTextFormat(myFormat);
    mc3.addChild(myText);
    addChild(mc3);
    mc3.x = _can.x;
    mc3.y = p;
    p= mc3.y+mc3.height+10;
    mc3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,_select)
}
function _select(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    tool_stage.combo.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,_font);
}
function _font(e:Event):void
{
    format.font = tool_stage.combo.selectedLabel;
    myText.setTextFormat(format);
}
```

Comment: First off, what comes up when you run this? Also, `addChild(mc3)` should go before `mc3.addChild(myText)`.

Comment: run is successfull.but  i want to format of selected textfield.this code create formate only last textField.

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer:

```
function _font(e:Event):void
{
    format.font = tool_stage.combo.selectedLabel;
    var mc:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip;
    (mc.getChildAt(0) as TextField).setTextFormat(format);
}
```

Comment: textformat applied latest create textfield.i want to change format of any selected textfield.

Comment: my apologies - i didnt read the question properly. I dont think there is a way to apply textFormat to all TextFields at once.